# how to execute javascript in delphi?

Tags: javascript, delphi, browser

I am coding a small app ,in middle i struck at some point where i have to execute javascript to get my data ?

in my process ,i have to login to some url and then go to some page and have to get data from that . i done all this with indy idhttp ,i got all info except one column which needs javascript to get value ,then i tried using twebbowser to make it work for me ,but how can i use cookies to enabled to webbrowser ?

i navigated browserto('http://mysite.com/login.php user and pass ') ,well its loged in and then i tried to access next link like ('http://mysite.com/link1/example.php')but it directing to login page :(

any help appreciated :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your best bet would be to automate IE itself.  Grab a copy of [embeddedwb](http://www.bsalsa.com/downloads.html), drop on a form and navigate to the url which you need to execute something.  There is a document property of the component which returns an OLEVariant, use this to execute a DHTML style statement.. something like `document.form.submit;`.

You can easily hide the window used for automation, one technique I have used is to place it on a new page on a page control, add a second page to display the status, then show the status page and hide the tabs.

Comment: do you know if this can be done in a Windows Service?  Or does it have to be a Win32 App?

Answer (score 7):

What is your question now? In the title you ask how to execute JavaScript. Try the following:

```
uses
  MSHTML_TLB, SHDocVw, ShellAPI;

function ExecuteScript(doc: IHTMLDocument2; script: string; language: string): Boolean;
var
  win: IHTMLWindow2;
  Olelanguage: Olevariant;
begin
  if doc <> nil then
  begin
    try
      win := doc.parentWindow;
      if win <> nil then
      begin
        try
          Olelanguage := language;
          win.ExecScript(script, Olelanguage);
        finally
          win := nil;
        end;
      end;
    finally
      doc := nil;
    end;
  end;
end;
```

Sample usage:

```
IDoc: IHTMLDocument2;
Webbrowser1.Document.QueryInterface(IHTMLDocument2, iDoc);
ExecuteScript(iDoc, 'document.login.submit()', 'JavaScript');
```

(This, and more, can be found [here](http://www.swissdelphicenter.ch/de/showcode.php?id=1732)).

---

Then in the text you ask how to use **cookies** (when using TWebBrowser this should happen automatically). When using Indy HTTP, you just have to attach a `TIdCookieManager` to your `TIdHTTPClient` instance, thats all (but you probably don't want to use that anyway, due to the script requirement....)